# Chrome.devtools.network api gives undefinded when called in devtools.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am building a chrome extension with manifest version 3.0. I am trying to capture the service calls details of a webpage. I created a devtoolsPage and tried accessing the chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener api but getting **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'network')** error

```
{
  "manifest version": 3,
  "name": "Demo",
  "short_name": "Demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Demo  project",
  "devtools_page": "devTools.html",
  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*//*",
    "https://*/*",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html?s/popup",
    "default_title": "Demo"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": [
      ],
      "js": [
      ]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "serviceworker.js"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "web_accessible resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["main.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ]
}
```

devTools.html

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="devTools.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

devTools.js

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("Demo",
"./demo.png",
"./index.html",
function(panel) {}
);
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
 function(event) {
console.log("A service event has occurred.");
});
```

Everytime i add the extension and navigate through the page i get the following error.

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'network')**
at the **chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(** in the devTools.js file.

Comment: Don't navigate through the page. Open devtools, then open your panel. Also remove ` : any`

Comment: Hello wOxxOm thanks for replying, I need to capture the service calls that a page makes, in order to do that I require to navigate to pages please let me know if any alternative than this.... and removing: any doesn't have any affect

Comment: An extension page should have `chrome-extension://id/pagename.html` URL.